# jquery animate function in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

I've been struggling with this for the past few days. I've read everything that is regarding closures and problems with having them in loops. But using a jquery animate function in a loop just isn't working for me. But maybe I didn't understand the actual point behind closures, that's why I'm asking :)
So, here's the example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var obj1 = $(".wraper");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    alert("Calling animate");
    obj1.animate({"opacity": 0.4}, 500, function() {     
        alert("Animate finished");
    });
}
});
```

I want the sequence to be called as follows:

1. Calling animate
2. Animate finished
3. Calling animate
4. Animate finished
5. Calling animate
6. Animate finished

What I get is:

1. Calling animate
2. Calling animate
3. Animate finished
4. Calling animate
5. Animate finished
6. Animate finished

Now, after reading about closures I would say this isn't the same problem all the answers are using in these situations, usualy it's related to using the counter i inside the function declaration, but here it's related to the order in which the callback is called, I don't know how jquery library calls the animate  callback, can anyone help me with this?

Note:
If used it like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var obj1 = $(".wraper");
       for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) (function(n) {
           alert("Calling animate");
           obj1.animate({"opacity": 0.4}, 500, function() {  
              alert("Animate finished");
           });
       })(i);
    }
```

So, making each iteration as a self executing function block (that's how I understood it, please correct me if I'm wrong?), I get the same result as above!

Comment: The loop runs immediately, so all the `animate` functions start right away, at the same time, with maybe a few milliseconds difference. As javascript timers aren't very accurate, jQuery's `animate()` won't be able to maintain order of the callbacks, as it's not accurate down to a few milliseconds.

Comment: `animate` is asynchronous. Your loop is working, but all animations run at the same time. If you want to wait you have to do the next animation within the callback, and the next one within the callback of the previous one, and so on. But there are ways to avoid callback hell.

Comment: @adeneo: So your saying that callback is called based on a timer or? I thought it is fired imidiatelly after the animation finishes?

Comment: It is called when the animation is finished, but jQuery creates that animation using timers, like `setTimeout`, and it's not accurate down to the millisecond, so you can't expect the callbacks to finish in the same order they were called in the loop, as all the animations are started almost at the same time

Comment: Hm, I see, you're correct.The order of the printouts proves it. But I'm still slightly puzzled, isn't javascript single threaded? So, it should wait until each animate (timeout) finishes before it continues on the next iteration?

Comment: are you open to trying out other JS animation libraries, in particular **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)**. This _sequencing_ that you are trying to do is one of the many things GSAP excels at. Take a look at **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/dw7ofjdy/)** for example. And just by changing a few properties, the same can be updated to **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/dw7ofjdy/1/)**. I highly recommend looking into GSAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of for loop you can use recursive anonymous function:

```
var i = 0;
(function recur() {
    if (i < 3) {
        i++;
        alert("Calling animate");
        obj1.animate({"opacity": 0.4}, 500, function() {     
            alert("Animate finished");
            recur();
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks jcubic, it works! I see, so we're actually stating here that only the next iteration will be executed only after the callback is executed, nice!

Comment: @user1809732 if it solve your problem don't forget to mark the answer.